# mysql return row with higher value

Tags: mysql

I have a table of reviews that looks a bit like this

```
ID    REVIEWITEM  SCORE    DATE
1     Object A    5.0      6-5-2012
2     Object A    7.0      6-5-2012
3     Object A    6.0      6-7-2012
4     Object B    4.0      7-1-2012
```

I want to have a have a query return to me all of the reviews, but if the reviews are for the same item and have the same date, to just return the review with the higher score.  So for example above the results would be:

```
ID    REVIEWITEM  SCORE    DATE
2     Object A    7.0      6-5-2012
3     Object A    6.0      6-7-2012
4     Object B    4.0      7-1-2012
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Are those really how your dates are stored?  You ought to be using [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html)!

Comment: it isn't actually how the dates are stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC, SCORE DESC GROUP BY REVIEWITEM, DATE
```

SHOULD WORK

Answer (score 6):

give this a try,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   tableName a INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ReviewItem, `Date`, MAX(SCORE) maxScore
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY ReviewItem, `Date`
        ) b ON a.reviewItem = b.reviewItem AND
                a.score = b.maxScore AND
                a.`date` = b.`date`
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d70b/5)

Comment: For correctness, you should probably join table by column id, but otherwise what you wrote should work.

Comment: although this is correct and would be the way to go if the tables were more complicated, Suresh's answer is just faster

Comment: @DerickF are yo sure you tested your accepted answer? It will not work on other RBDMS (*I mean if you try to switch to MSSQL or ORACLE*) and the query is not correct. You are probably looking for small but not "efficient" query. :/

Comment: Yup, i tested both answers, checked the results, and compared the times before choosing an answer.  I fully agree that your answer is probably better for most applications, but for my specific project John's answer is a better fit.  I must thank you though because i did learn something new from your answer and have applied it in another area in my code, but it wasn't the answer for this specific problem.